# How to calculate the limit?

Tags: limits

How to compute the below limit :

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,1)}\, \frac{(x - 1)^{2} - (y - 1)^{2}}{|x - 1| + |y - 1|}$$

Comment: Have you tried setting $x(t) = y(t) = t$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac{(x-1)^2-(y-1)^2}{|x-1|+|y-1|}$

$=\frac{|x-1|^2-|y-1|^2}{|x-1|+|y-1|}$

$=\frac{(|x-1|+|y-1|)(|x-1|-|y-1|)}{|x-1|+|y-1|}$

$=|x-1|-|y-1|$

Now take the limit.